# Conflict Gson and CSV?

Tags: java, csv, gson

I have a method that have to print a CSV and have to send a JSON to answer an ajax call.

This is the code that includes both:

```
//Print of CSV
ByteArrayOutputStream os = (ByteArrayOutputStream)builder.buildCsvToStream(tableDataMatrixTemp);
getThreadLocalResponse().setContentType("text/csv");
getThreadLocalResponse().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=QuerySql_" + date + ".csv");

//Gson creation
Gson gson = new Gson();
String objectJson = gson.toJson("OK");


OutputStream responseOutputStream = getThreadLocalResponse().getOutputStream();
os.writeTo(responseOutputStream);
responseOutputStream.write(objectJson.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The ajax call doesn't receive the JSON *and* the CSV is not printed (not downloaded), I fear that the CSV and the JSON came on conflict. Can someone fix this, please?

Comment: Your HTTP response can have only one media type. If you want to send multiple files, you're going to need to add some custom magic over the top of HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

On the server-side you still need to flush and close the `OutputStream`.

```
responseOutputStream.flush();
responseOutputStream.close();
```

On the front end side you need to download the file either by `window.open` or by creating an iframe like this:

```
$.post('/your-url', postData, function(retData) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", retData.url);
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

Hope it does the trick for you!

Comment: Uhm forgive me for question: where i have to flush-code? At end or after sent the json?

Comment: after you write to the output stream